# What word or phrase can I use to replaced the word "stopped" in the following text?

Tags: word-choice

This is the text:

> Erin scanned the room for a moment. She suddenly **stopped**, and
>   went over to the bookshelf. Then, as if she were searching for a secret
>   passage, she examined each book carefully.

(By **stopped**, it means that Erin suddenly stopped scanning the room and fixed her eyes on the bookshelf).

I'm not very sure about this but I think words like **stopped** and **came to an halt** are more commonly used to refer to someone who stopped **walking** or **running** (not sue if **came to a stop** sounds better).

Is there any other word or phrase that I can use in my example above? (unless **stopped** is perfectly right in this situation).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with ***stopped***. It simply means that she ceased her present activity.

Comment: writing advice off topic. might try [writers.se].

Comment: If you had meant to say something other than *stopped* there, then you must try to express that verb, else the question will result in speculative answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My choices would be "paused", "hesitated" or "halted".

Comment: But this is really a general reference question. See a thesaurus.

Answer (score 1):

"stopped" is perfectly common to use to indicate cessation of any activity.  He stopped reading.  He stopped scanning the room.  She stopped calculating differential equations.  The lawnmower suddenly stopped.

If there is a particular implication that you are aiming for, you might want to check the dictionary for all meanings of "stopped", then check the thesaurus for all synonyms, and the dictionary for all meanings of those synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

The first word that came to mind when I read the sentence was "paused." As in, "she suddenly paused." That could refer to movement, but I have no trouble thinking that it refers to her scanning of the books.
However, 'stopped', as well, works fine in the context. 'Paused' just seems to be a slightly more descriptive choice.